# Can't migrate large repo from gitlab to github

Tags: git, github, repository, gitlab, git-lfs

I am trying to migrate a private repo from Gitlab to Github. It contains some large files which are tracked using git LFS. Even after that, I am not able to push the repo to GitHub. The size of the repo is huge as it's the full codebase for an operating system and size of the repo is around 75GB.

When I am trying to push it to GitHub, I'm getting the following logs.

```
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (8600/8600), 5.9 GB | 0 B/s, done
Enumerating objects: 472049, done.
Counting objects: 100% (472049/472049), done.
Compressing objects: 100% (302043/302043), done.
kex protocol error: type 7 seq 16549), 1020.66 MiB | 4.88 MiB/s
kex protocol error: type 7 seq 32979), 1.99 GiB | 4.83 MiB/s
remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Please let me know if there is any way to bypass the size limit.

Comment: Try pushing previous revisions of branches and then go forward.... I guess that should work. `git push upstream master~10000:master; git push upstream master~9000:master;` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GitHub does not allow a single push to exceed 2 GB to prevent certain types of DoS attacks. You'll need to push this repository incrementally unless you're using the GitHub import utility.

You can do that by running something like this:

```
git rev-list --reverse --all | ruby -ne 'x ||=0; x += 1; print $_ if x % 30000 == 0;' | xargs -I{} echo git push github +{}:refs/heads/master
git push github +master
git push --mirror github
```

This pushes 30000 commits at a time. Once those are all pushed, it pushes the `master` branch one final time to contain the correct data, and then mirrors the rest of the repository.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But right now the problem I'm having is the root commit is around 50GB as at that time our OS was nothing but vanilla AOSP source code. So is there any way to solve the issue? Or, I need to split the commits into multiple ones and rewrite the whole git history?

Comment: GitHub usually does not let people have such large repositories. You'll need to reach out to GitHub support and ask them to raise the limit for the repository, although in all likelihood they will ask you to rewrite the repository.

Comment: this is a great answer if you have one branch (master). but what if you have many branches?

Comment: You push the main branch first that way, and then you push the rest of the branches, which is what `git push --mirror github` does.  Usually, most of those branches will contain very few extra commits, and pushing them all at once will work.  If you have other branches with significant history, you may need to push those incrementally first.